# How to add a stop button in an iframe?

Tags: html

How do add a stop button in my iframe so that only the pages which are being viewed in the iframe are stopped and not the parent page itself.

Thanking you,

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "stop" the page?

Comment: "stop" the page? not following this at all. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean to stop the iframe page from loading, as though the user had clicked the browser's "Stop" button, but for the top-level page to continue, correct?

There is no way I know of to get the browser to add its stop button to the iframe, but you can add a button yourself and stop it with javascript. If you can access the content of the iframe, then something like this should work:

```
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopFrameLoad(); return false;"/>
```

And in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function stopFrameLoad()
 {
    window.stop(); //NS only
    document.execCommand("Stop"); //IE only
 }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if the window.stop will throw on IE; I never tested it. If it does, you'd be better to put the IE method in the catch.

If you don't have access to the iframe content then you can probably access it via its id tag and then set its location to about:blank, or something along those lines.

Although to be honest it's likely that there is a better way to handle whatever you're trying to do. Why would you want to stop the iframes loading and not the main page? If you can access the main page to add code in, why not just remove the iframes from there?